# Access Duplicates with a different value

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have a table with Customer#, Item#, and Price. I need to find duplicates of Customer# and Item# but with different price. I ran the built in duplicate query and tried modifying it but nothing is spitting out the correct results. I appreciate any and all help on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running a self join like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, c.ItemID, c.Price
FROM MyTable c INNER JOIN 
(SELECT CustomerID, ItemID, Price
    FROM MyTable) c2
ON c2.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
AND c2.ItemID = c.ItemID 
WHERE c.Price <> c2.Price
```